# How to convert dataframe from wide to long format with multiple columns r

Tags: r

I have dataframe which looks like this, `df1`:

```
ID   Name         Date          col1  col2  col3
 1    Pete    "2021-01-01"       6     10   30
 1    Pete    "2021-02-01"       5     9    10
 1    Pete    "2021-03-01"       3     20   90
 2    Alex    "2021-01-01"       3     20   80
 2    Alex    "2021-02-01"       6     10   30
 2    Alex    "2021-02-01"       12    80   40
```

The `Date` column has a Date type. Now, I want to make this table where there is only one row per person and where the values over time are in the columns. Hence, it should look like this, `df_result`:

```
ID   Name col1_"2021-01-01"  col1_"2021-02-01" col1_"2021-03-01"  col2_"2021-01-01"  col2_"2021-02-01" col2_"2021-03-01"
1    Pete    6                      5                 3               10                      9             20
```

And this for all the rows and columns. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**tidyverse**

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_wider(
    c(ID, Name),
    names_from = Date,
    values_from = starts_with("col"),
    values_fn = toString
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 x 11
#>      ID Name  col1_01.01.2021 col1_01.02.2021 col1_01.03.2021 col2_01.01.2021
#>   <int> <chr> <chr>           <chr>           <chr>           <chr>          
#> 1     1 Pete  6               5               3               10             
#> 2     2 Alex  3               6, 12           <NA>            20             
#> # ... with 5 more variables: col2_01.02.2021 <chr>, col2_01.03.2021 <chr>,
#> #   col3_01.01.2021 <chr>, col3_01.02.2021 <chr>, col3_01.03.2021 <chr>
```

**data.table**

<sup>Created on 2021-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)              
value_var <- c("col1", "col2", "col3")
dcast(data = df, formula = ID + Name ~ Date, fun.aggregate = toString, value.var = value_var)
#>    ID Name col1_01.01.2021 col1_01.02.2021 col1_01.03.2021 col2_01.01.2021
#> 1:  1 Pete               6               5               3              10
#> 2:  2 Alex               3           6, 12                              20
#>    col2_01.02.2021 col2_01.03.2021 col3_01.01.2021 col3_01.02.2021
#> 1:               9              20              30              10
#> 2:          10, 80                              80          30, 40
#>    col3_01.03.2021
#> 1:              90
#> 2:
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

**data**

```
df <-
  structure(
    list(
      ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
      Name = c("Pete", "Pete", "Pete", "Alex", "Alex", "Alex"),
      Date = c(
        "01.01.2021",
        "01.02.2021",
        "01.03.2021",
        "01.01.2021",
        "01.02.2021",
        "01.02.2021"
      ),
      col1 = c(6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 12L),
      col2 = c(10L, 9L, 20L, 20L, 10L, 80L),
      col3 = c(30L, 10L, 90L, 80L, 30L, 40L)
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-6L)
  )
```

Comment: Do you also know how to use this approach if the column names are different, so not always starting with `col`?

Comment: you can explicitly list using the parameter `values_from = c("col1", "col2", "col3")`